# How can I inspect and select an element from a pop up menu for playwright?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, automation, puppeteer, playwright

[an example with google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmp35.png)

I have been trying to select an element from the pop-up menu of google sheets, but I can not manage to find the element when I inspect it. How would I go about locating the html for the specific pop up menu?

I tried enabling left click on the elements using a chrome extension but I still am unable to locate the element.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
await page.locator(`#docs-file-menu`).click();
await page.locator(`[aria-label='Open o'`].click();
```

With google sheets open, you can just open the dev tools in chrome (F12) and inspect the elements from there.